# error TS2339: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

so I'm working on my ionic4 app and got an error on the **auth** in the try-catch block. I have tried installing the firebase package and adding the ***auth*** import but nothing seems to be working. What could be the problem?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Auth } from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseAuthService {
  auth: any[];

  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  async registerWithEmailPassword(email, password) {
    try {
      const result = await this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      await this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest AngularFireAuth, you do not need to specify .auth anymore.

you can directly access angularFireAuth.currentUser to get the user information.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have removed the .auth specifications on both lines of code but I am now being prompted to use 'await' on the 'sendEmailVerification() ' method. What can I do?

Comment: try this:

  this.angularFireAuth.currentUser.then(u => u.sendEmailVerification())
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email']);
    });